# Selecting a column with keywords from another column of another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help with a probably simple SQL problem. quite new with SQL so not sure how to solve this. 
My problem is that i'm trying to select a columnA where the data in the column contains keywords from another columnB in tableB. an example of how the data is as below.

```
tableA, columnA : {'This apple is red', 'This ball is round', 'This chair is metal'}
tableB, columnB : {'red', 'round'}
```

Now im thinking something like this query

```
SELECT columnA FROM tableA
WHERE columnA LIKE '%' + (SELECT columnB FROM tableB) + '%'
```

So obviously it won't work because the subquery returns more than 1 value. I'm trying to see some other functions to use like CURSOR but I can't figure it out. Help is very appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `EXISTS` instead:

```
SELECT columnA FROM tableA A
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tableB B where A.columnA LIKE '%' + B.columnB + '%')
```

Comment: this works! tyvm :D. how does the select 1 works in this case? how did it iterate to every row? Also just wondering, how about if the keywords are not just one word? lets say its {'is red', 'is round'} instead. now this is not needed in my case but if it's like this and I want to so that it can still select a row that is 'this apple is very red' and not just 'this apple is red' because there was a 'very' at the middle. much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
select * from tableA A
JOIN tableB B on A.columnA  like '%' + B.columnB +'%'
```

Comment: May return duplicates, e.g if columnB contains both 'red' and 'cred', and columnA has 'cred'.